# Modelica - How to use units in equations

Tags: parameters, equation, modelica

How can i use units directly in equations in Modelica? Is that possible at all?
Simple example, a parameter, that should be made dependant (as default value) to another parameter of a different unit. In the example below it would give a unit warning (naturally). How do i say i just want the nominal value of the variable and not the value+unit ?

```
model customspringdamper
  import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
  parameter SI.TranslationalSpringConstant c =100;
  parameter SI.TranslationalDampingConstant d= 0.01*c;
  ... < rest of stuff > ...
end customspringdamper;
```

Of course i could define another parameter with a unit and value 1 but this feels more laborous than neccessary?

Comment: The parameter could have value 0.01 and unit, then you do not need the 0.01 anymore at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see three ways:

1. Declare the parameter as Real without the unit: `parameter Real c =100;` You lose the unit-checking, but it doesn't seem that you use it.
2. Use constants to convert the value to a different unit:

`import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
 parameter SI.TranslationalSpringConstant c= 100;
 parameter SI.TranslationalDampingConstant d= 0.01*(c/unitSpring)*unitDamping;
 constant SI.TranslationalSpringConstant unitSpring=1;
 constant SI.TranslationalDampingConstant unitDamping=1;`

Tools should be able to simplify the code to remove those constants. However, you circumvent unit-checking which makes your code more error-prone.

There are some cases where it is legitimate to remove units in this way - but not in cases like this.

3. Basically the same as 2, but you put the units on `0.01`; and give it an actual physical meaning:

   `import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
   parameter SI.TranslationalSpringConstant c= 100;
   parameter SI.Time SpringTime=0.01;
   parameter SI.TranslationalDampingConstant d= SpringTime*c;`

Comment: I would like to use the unit checking - but cases like this throw many warnings, hence why i was looking for a solution.
Thanks for the options - i must admit, that i'd have hoped for a possibility of direct use of units. such as "d = 0.01 * c * SI.Time" for example.

For parameters it's ok-ish i guess, but for the graphical schematic view(Realexpressions or Gain blocks for example) the available options seem inconvenient and feels more like a workaround than a proper solution. E.g. if i have a Sensorsignal and i want to convert the signal to a different unit.